# Updating input, to update variable, to update table

Tags: jquery, if-statement, variables

I am trying to create a simple table where you enter a registration number, and then the car name is put in to the cell adjacent to it.

I am using variables and when writing the if statement, it goes either one of two ways despite the conditions.

Below is the code for the if statement:

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function(){
$(this).closest('td').text($(this).val())});

var car1 = "Little White";
var car_1_reg = "NP60UQQ";

var car_reg_1 = $("#car-1-reg").html();
var car_name_1 = $("#car-1-name").html();
$(".confirm").click(function() {
if (car_reg_1 != car_1_reg) {
    car_name_1.innerText = 'Not a valid Registration';
}   else {
    car_name_1.textContent = car1;
}});
```

and I have uploaded the full project to jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/pyho3as2/1/

I have spent most of the day trying to get the first part to work, once I have that right I can apply the logic across to the other parts (enter miles left and update miles till charge etc.

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're reading the dynamic-input during `doc.ready`, so it will never have the updated value.  This needs to move into the `click` handler:

```
var car_reg_1 = $("#car-1-reg").html();
$(".confirm").click(function() {
    if (car_reg_1 != car_1_reg) {
```

becomes

```
$(".confirm").click(function() {
    var car_reg_1 = $("#car-1-reg").html();
    if (car_reg_1 != car_1_reg) {
```

next is that `#car-1-reg` is an input, so need to use `.val()`

```
var car_reg_1 = $("#car-1-reg").val();
```

however, the `input` for car-1-reg is removed from the DOM with this line in the input change event

```
$(this).closest('td').text($(this).val());
```

so at the time of checking (inside the click event) that element no longer exists `$("#car-1-reg").length === 0)` with the value now stored in the parent `td`.

There are two ways to fix this

1. Give the `td` an id that you can reference, eg

and access that (inside the confirm click handler)

```
var car_reg_1 = $("#car-1-reg-td").text();
```

updated fiddle using this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/6oLvp7f5/

or

2. don't remove the input, but hide it

```
<td><span></span><input id="car-1-reg"...
```

and

```
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').find("span").show().text($(this).val());
    $(this).hide();
});
```

then you can reference the input directly in the confirm click handler (using `.val()`).

This also has the advantage that if you ever want a "reset" you can hide the `span` and show the `input`.

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much for taking the time to write all of that out and explain it to me. I will attempt to fix this first thing tomorrow. Now I am watching my son while my partner goes to work. Thank you again :)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, I have just tried your suggestion (went for hiding the span) and it works perfectly thank you! I have up voted (several times) but as my reputation is below 15 it says m vote isn't public but still counts. Thank you again! With your help I am hoping to finish the rest of the reflection and get the project submitted by the end of the day!Have a good day and thank you again! :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but I tried this to add the rest:

$(".reset").click(function() {
    $("span[type='text']").change(function(){
        $(this).closest('td').find("span").hide().text($(this).val());
        $("input").show();
    });
});

And it's obviously not working, am I being stupid here just changing input to span and vice versa?

Comment: `$("span[type='text']")` won't work as it's not type=text - you'll need to reference them someother way, eg adding a class to the spans or the tds or referencing them some other way such as  `$("input[text=text]").closest("td").find("span")` - note that the `span` won't have a `change` event.  Probably best to ask a new question as this answer is for your original question.

Comment: Thank you! I will try and solve it myself based what you have said, don't want to just get given the answers all the time. But if I fail I will definitely ask a separate question. Thanks again for your reply and advice :)

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to up-vote if it's helpful and accept if it solves the issue (I believe there's a short time limit on accepting)

Comment: I keep trying to up vie but my rep is below 15 so isn't public.. It's 11 at the minute, I've asked another question, here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742394/getting-nan-when-trying-to-use-a-number-from-an-input-field-in-an-if-statment?noredirect=1#comment112717571_63742394 and thought it goes up with each question asked.. but it stayed at 11..

Comment: No worries, thanks.  I've upvoted your question (apologies, should have done this earlier) which will help.