# Getting NaN when trying to use a number from an input field in an if statment

Tags: jquery, if-statement, numbers, cell

I am having a problem with part of my reflection. I am trying to get table cell to show how many miles are left until charging the car is needed.

I have an input cell where the user would type how many miles are left (50) and then a calculation happens (50 - (10% buffer, 25) = 25 and displays on the cell next to it.

I have gone through the questions on here I can find and tried the approaches others have tried but I really am at a dead end now.

The JSFiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/Coxy/gr5bcnsq/

The code is

```
var car_1_mtnc = document.getElementById('car-1-mtnc');
$(".confirm").click(function() {
var a =  parseInt(document.getElementById('car-1-cmra').value, 10);
var miles = a - 25;  

if ( a != Number ) {
    car_1_mtnc.textContent = "Please enter the miles left";
} else {
    car_1_mtnc.textContent = miles;
}
});
```

HTML

```
                                    <td><span id="car-1-cmra" class="answer" type="number"></span><input id="car-1-cmr" class="cmr" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Miles Left"></input></td>
                                    <td id="car-1-mtnc" class="mtnc"></td>
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Your jsfiddle-snippet has `TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`

Comment: I'm using the DataTable plug in, it still works for me in JSFiddle when i try adding the Car reg :/ I'll look and see if I missed anything.

Comment: There's (currently) no issue with `.DataTable` in the linked fiddle.  That can happen with a wrong link of if there's a script error somewhere, but that part of the fiddle is working fine for me - maybe Sascha blocking the CDN for some obscure reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

The first is that you're getting `.value` from `#car-1-crma` using

```
document.getElementById('car-1-cmra').value
```

but that's the swap-out `span` so doesn't have a .value - you can either use `.textContent` on the span or use the (now-)hidden input

```
document.getElementById('car-1-cmr').value
document.getElementById('car-1-cmra').textContent
$("#car-1-cmra").text()
```

The second is that you are using

```
if (a != Number)
```

as alluded to in the comments, to check if an input is a number or not, you use

```
if (isNaN(a))
```

Making those two changes fixes your fiddle for the miles range calculation: https://jsfiddle.net/4m8pa9dh (input value)  and https://jsfiddle.net/4m8pa9dh/1/ (span textContent)

Comment: My saviour again, thank you so much. I really appreciate all the help you have given me :) I will update the code Monday and let you know how it went. Thank you. I really am very grateful you take time out of your day to help me :)

Comment: I don't mean to be cheeky, but if you have the time I have another issue .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810440/create-a-hourly-charge-schedule-based-off-of-user-input-plug-in-or-build